# SQL merge two statements (CROSS JOIN)

Tags: mysql, sql

first of I'm not sure if I have set correctly title of this question.

I'm having little troubles with SQL stament I would like to make.
I have now two SQL statements, which are giving me results like this:

**First:**

```
SELECT column as service from table where something = "value 1"
```

service 
1 
2
3

```
SELECT column as city from table where something = "value 2"
```

**Second:**
city 
4
5

I'd like with only one SQL statement, the get the result like this:

service        city 
1                  4
1                         5
2                         4
 
2                         5
3                         4
3                         5

I'm quite sure that there is some solution to make it possible, I just cannot find out how should be solved.
If anyone could help me, I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `cross join`:

```
SELECT s.service, c.city
FROM (SELECT column as service from table where something = 'value 1'
     ) s CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT column as city from table where something = 'value 2'
     ) c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cross join

```
SELECT t1.column as service , t2.column as city
from table t1 
cross join table t2
where t1.something = "value 1" and   t2.something = "value 2"
```